# Sharepoint list in Angular loading slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have a Sharepoint list I'm trying to get items from and populate in an Angular app.  When the page loads, nothing is loaded, if I click off the page and click back the data shows up.  How can I get the items to load sooner, like before the page is initially loaded?

Here's my page controller.

```js
app.controller("organizationsCtrl", ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$location", "$routeParams", "spService", "dataService",
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $routeParams, spService, dataService) {

        $scope.editing = false;
        $scope.column = "id";
        $scope.reverse = false;

        $scope.organizations = dataService.getOrganizations();

        $scope.navToAdd = function() {
            $location.path("/organizations/add");
        }

        $scope.navToEdit = function(index) {
            $location.path("/organizations/" + index);
        };

        $scope.sortColumn = function(col) {
            $scope.column = col;
            if($scope.reverse) {
                $scope.reverse = false;
                //$scope.reverseclass = 'arrow-up';
            } else {
                $scope.reverse = true;
                //$scope.reverseclass = 'arrow-down';
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Here is my service.

```js
app.service('dataService', ['$rootScope', 'spService', function ($rootScope, spService) {
    var svc = {};

    var organizations = {};

    svc.getOrganizations = function() {
        spService.getRecords("Organizations", "?$select=ID,Title").then(function (result) {
            organizations = result;
        });
        return organizations;
    }

    return svc;
}]);
```